# Run Azure Web Job from a provided hosted app

Tags: sharepoint-online, timer-jobs, azure

I have an azure web job created in Azure and configured to "On demand" schedule. I can run this web job from Azure Web Apps UI using "Run Once" button.

I have a provided hosted app and it has a page with a button. I want run the azure web job on the provided hosted app page button click. Is it possible?

If Yes, how do we call/invoke/run azure web job from a page in my provided hosted app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done using the [WebJobs API](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/WebJobs-API). Assuming you want to call it from server side code:

```
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> InvokeWebJob()
    {
        using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://<azure site>.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/"); // replace with your site name
            var byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("username:key");    // you can get these details from your web job properties
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray));

            HttpResponseMessage responseMessage = null;
            try
            {
                responseMessage = await httpClient.PostAsync("triggeredwebjobs/<web job name>/run", null);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // logging etc.
            }
            return responseMessage;
        }
    }

    this can be invoked like this and this will trigger your on-demand web job:

    var task = InvokeWebJob();
    // TODO: Check for null etc.
    task.Wait();
    var result = task.Result;
```